# How to specify log4j2 absolute path in maven multimodule project?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, multi-module

I have a maven multi-module project with structure similar to: 
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-TexFkNoAwhYbHnyoxhyQJ6W7CHOBBzZ/view)

I have the following log4j2.properties file:

```
property.eventLogPath = src/main/resources/log/events/

appender.eventLogger.type = RollingFile
appender.eventLogger.name = eventLogger
appender.eventLogger.fileName=  ${eventLogPath}/app.log
appender.eventLogger.filePattern=  ${eventLogPath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.eventLogger.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.eventLogger.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level 
[%t] [%c] [%M] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.eventLogger.policies.type = Policies
# Rotate log file each day and keep 30 days worth
appender.eventLogger.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.eventLogger.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.eventLogger.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.eventLogger.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy

logger.event.name = event
logger.event.level = info
logger.event.additivity = false
logger.event.appenderRef.eventLogger.ref = eventLogger

rootLogger.level = error  
rootLogger.additivity = false
```

I have the following method:

```
private static Logger eventLogger = LogManager.getLogger("event");

public static void sendLog()  {
    eventLogger.info("event");
}
```

When I execute this method in my main/java and my test/java packages It will generate log dir in two diferent places. I try to execute this snippet of code in main/java and test/java packages to get user dir

```
  System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

And for main package it define:

```
   C:\Users\dev\IdeaProjects\multimodules\
```

For test package:

```
   C:\Users\dev\IdeaProjects\multimodules\users
```

Maybe this trouble in maven config but I can't refactor any config in maven.
And my question is the following:

Is it possible to define some relative path in property.eventLogPath in log4j2.properties that will be the same to all packages. Maybe it path will be relative to resources folder or log4j file. Or it can be absolute path but flexible for different OS something like this:

```
property.eventLogPath = ${sys:user.dir}/src/main/resources/log/events/
```